# Capture image from camera send server to client

Tags: c#, sockets

I try to stream camera server to client via TCP socket but i got error from client side is

> 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll - Parameter
>   is not valid.

at the line `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);`

here is server code

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[100000]; 
        var converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
        while (true) // find a better way to determine that the picture is still updating?
        {

            if (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(bit);
                Console.Write(bmp);
                buffer = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
                clientSocket.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                Console.Write(i++);
                GC.Collect();
            }
            else { MessageBox.Show("disconnect"); }
        }
```

here is client side

```
bool success = true;
        while (success)
        {
            if (s.Connected)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
                s.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                //ms.SetLength(0);
                GC.Collect();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnect");
            }
        }
        success = true;
        return;
```

Comment: Don't use an image converter. Save the bitmap to a memory stream. And drop the `GC.Collect()` statements. They do more harm than good. If you want to dispose the memory stream, use `using`.

Comment: can you show example for me i mean as you tell use using @sefe